# Help with Resident Evil Animations!

Tags: animation, rigging, .fbx

I'm totally new to Blender and I want to create some funny animations with Resident Evil characters, but I'm having trouble with 2 things.
I tried to import rigged characters from this site: (FBX file format)
https://rigmodels.com/index.php?searchkeyword=resident-evil
But they won't show up in Blender...(I'm using 4.0 version)

Then I tried to import in Wavefront Format and the character appeared.
But now I don't know if it's possible to make an animation with an wavefront object file; like rigging it, to begin with...
What do you suggest I do?

Comment: To be honest, the first thing you'll need to do is to learn Blender! You won't be able to animate anything if you've never used Blender before. It certainly isn't for complete beginners, especially animation.